# Avoid conflicts in Yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'd like to replace a partial in my app with a template when scaffolding with Yeoman. Everything seems to work out fine, but I get this conflict error during the scaffold.

`this.template(
'conditional-files/html/_signup.email.html', 'app/html/partials/_main.signup.html'
);`

`conflict app/html/partials/_main.signup.html
[?] Overwrite app/html/partials/_main.signup.html? (Ynaxdh)`

Is there a way to avoid this? I looked into passing a {status: 'force'} but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of options I can see:
 1. You can pass --force as an option to your yo command:  yo mygenerator --force
 2. can set generator.conflicter.force = true before calling the template function

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to allow you to force update the file.

```js
conflicts() {
    this.conflicter.force = true
  }
```