# Conflict Safe Append to Existing File in Yeoman Generator

Tags: javascript, django, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm writing a yeoman generator for a Django/Angular project I'm working on. A large part of the boilerplate in the project involves managing dependencies. To make this dependency management easier, I'm treating certain files essentially as header files that define what a certain package exports or imports. For example, when I create a new file `my_model.py` in my `my_app/models/` package, I'd like to append the line `from .my_model import MyModel` to `my_app/models/__init__.py`

Since this is just a simple append which doesn't particularly depend on what's in the rest of the `__init__.py` file, I consider it a pretty safe file update. My question is whether there's a way to flag particular file updates in yeoman as safe from a development perspective, thereby allowing a user to not have to sign off on them during the conflict resolution phase of running the generator.

Currently the way I'm executing the append is this:

```
var self = this;
this.fs.copy(
  this.destinationPath(this.props.appName + '/models/__init__.py'),
  this.destinationPath(this.props.appName + '/models/__init__.py'),
  { 
    process: function (contents) {
      return contents += 'from .' + _.snakeCase(self.props.modelName) + ' import ' + self.props.modelName + '\n';
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to sign off on a conflict. It's not your responsibility to decide for your end user what is "safe" and what is not.

What if you introduce a bug and that's breaking the user file? That's why generators cannot skip conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you might want to replace some files, for example replace gulp or grunt file on first run when i.e. pulling out framework source code...

Toby gives a good way to do it here: 
[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492542/avoid-conflicts-in-yeoman-generator)